Alternative to OpenCV blob detection
I am trying to detect some markers on an image. However, with the markers being white, the SimpleBlobDetector of OpenCV gets confused by any glare.
For example, in the attached image, I can only detect 6 of the 7 markers (the 4 rings are ring lights and I do not want to detect them).

Could someone suggest a simple algorithm that could detect the 7th blob (on the le
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up the blob detector
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 255
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 50  # Adjust based on your ball size
params.maxArea = 400
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.8  # Circular blobs
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.9
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
                        
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
keypoints = detector.detect(gray)
                           
img_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, 
                                       keypoints, 
                                       np.array([]), 
                                       (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imshow('Detected Balls', img_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(5)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       


Can you post an original image?

fix the issue before it happens: reduce your exposure. your angle thingy is shiny/reflective. you don't want that showing up so brightly. the balls are supposed to glow more than any regular reflection.

@toyotaSupra, here's the original. Thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kuvm2h12164btwyp4e51k/Camera_2.jpg?rlkey=5r3you7998ok6j8aze4qnlz5t&dl=0

@ChristophRackwitz, I totally agree. However, the data does not belong to me, I just need to make something out of it. If it is not easily fixable, I will train an ML-based feature detector, but I thought I ask before. I don't have too much experience with OpenCV, so I can be overlooking something simple.

yeah train a detector. it'll learn to jump on round things, hopefully, even if there is some debris "connected" to it (the reflection on the angle bar). the model will probably not need to be very complex but you'll want to come up with synthetic data, so you can have lots of it for training. -- or reject that picture as too much hassle to work with.
